# Checking a file for certain values and output warnings

Tags: r

I would like to know how can I check a certain file for any values that I do not want and
if they are there, it should put out a warning.

This is just a trivial example, but lets say we have a data set like this:

```
df<- data.frame(test_number_1=c("xaa77"),test_number_2=c("xaaa7777"),
                test_number_3=c("!xxxxaaaa?7c"))
```

And I would like to check, if for example, if this data set has a `c` in it ( here it 
is at the end in one of them), and I woud like to output a warning if there is something like that.

Next, I would like to check if it has a `!` at the beginning. If it has not, then it
should put out a warning message.

Another thing would be if it has certain characters, that I can allow ( something like a list of characters), and if it doesnt have them, it should put a warning. In this example, the row in the data set should only have `7,x,a`, and not `c`.

What is more, if it has a `?` in it, should put a warning and remove it from the data set.

And if there is a upper case value, it should put lower case them, after it check them.

So, I am just interested in a general structure of commands for checking certain values in a dataset. Lets say a for loop for checking every character in this data set or a bigger function. You dont have to write all these rules, just a handout for these of control structures.

Comment: I suggest you write a function.  But you'd need to read the file to know what's in it.  Perhaps use `readLines` with a series of `grep` (or `grepl`) commands

Comment: If I wanted to do it with grep or grepl, how can I write the commnad if it has a `value=true`, that it should give a warning? How can I combine that with a ifelse? Could you provide just one example?

Comment: `if(any(grepl("whatever", vector))) warning("here is the warning")`, something like that.  If you want to show the specific line where this occurred, you'd want to save a `grep` call and use `sprintf` to develop a specific warning message that tells the user which line the warning is on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, you could write a function.  Here's a short one that is very basic, but should give you a good start.

First I create a file with some text data, based on your data.

```
x <- c("xaa77", "xaaa7777", "!xxxxaaaa?7c")
writeLines(x, "new.txt")
```

Then here's a basic function that checks reads the data and checks it, producing a warning if `char` is found in the data.

```
fileCheck <- function(fname, char, fixed = FALSE) {
    r <- readLines(fname)
    if(length(g <- grep(char, r, fixed = fixed))) {
        warning(sprintf("\ncharacter '%s' found on line %d", char, g))
    }
    r
}
```

And here are a few sample runs:

```
fileCheck("new.txt", "c")
# [1] "xaa77"        "xaaa7777"     "!xxxxaaaa?7c"
# Warning message:
# In fileCheck("new.txt", "c") : 
# character 'c' found on line 3
fileCheck("new.txt", "!")
# [1] "xaa77"        "xaaa7777"     "!xxxxaaaa?7c"
# Warning message:
# In fileCheck("new.txt", "!") : 
# character '!' found on line 3
fileCheck("new.txt", "x")
# [1] "xaa77"        "xaaa7777"     "!xxxxaaaa?7c"
# Warning message:
# In fileCheck("new.txt", "x") : 
# character 'x' found on line 1
# character 'x' found on line 2
# character 'x' found on line 3
fileCheck("new.txt", "D")
# [1] "xaa77"        "xaaa7777"     "!xxxxaaaa?7c"
fileCheck("new.txt", "7777", fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "xaa77"        "xaaa7777"     "!xxxxaaaa?7c"
# Warning message:
# In fileCheck("new.txt", "7777", fixed = TRUE) : 
# character '7777' found on line 2
```

Hopefully that helps get you going.

Comment: Yeah, it will keep me going! Thanks a lot!